# RInside: can not read R["R.version.string"] as string

Tags: rcpp, rinside

I'm trying to read the value of R.version.string using the operator []. As a result an exception is thrown. Instead, with R.parseEval("R.version.string") is OK. Below is the example rinside_sample0.cpp modified showing the issue.

```
#include <RInside.h>                    // for the embedded R via RInside

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    RInside R(argc, argv);              // create an embedded R instance 

    try {
    std::string versionKO = R["R.version.string"];
    } catch(std::exception& ex) {
    std::cerr << "Exception caught: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
    } catch(...) {
    std::cerr << "Unknown exception caught" << std::endl;
    }

    std::string versionOK = R.parseEval("R.version.string");
    std::cout << versionOK << std::endl;

    R["txt"] = "Hello, world!\n";   // assign a char* (string) to 'txt'

    R.parseEvalQ("cat(txt)");           // eval the init string, ignoring any returns

    exit(0);
}
```

The output obtained is:

```
Exception caught: expecting a string
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Hello, world!
```

Comment: Please **DO NOT DOUBLE POST**.  I just replied to, and closed, your GitHub issue ticket.  There is no issue your question, apart from you wrongly assuming that the first approach should work. It won't, and that ain't no bug ...

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been solved on https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rinside/issues/9. The variable R.version.string is visible in the base environment and it can be retrieved like this:

```
Rcpp::Environment baseEnv("package:base");
std::string versionR = baseEnv["R.version.string"];
```